# Can not retrieve file from gridFs using the java driver (but can using python)

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs, mongodb-java

NOTE; we've completely rewritten the backend in python now, so even though it would still be nice to know what we did wrong, it's not that big of a thing anymore.

I've got a known file in my database that has the following objectID "5251ad0d56c02c34fbad2a3d"

I know it's there, since I can inspect it both with the mongo cli client and with pymongo:

```
>>> import pymongo, gridfs, bson
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient()
>>> db = client['playtest']
>>> fs = gridfs.GridFS(db, 'attachments')
>>> gridout = fs.get(bson.objectid.ObjectId("5251ad0d56c02c34fbad2a3d"))
>>> gridout.filename
u'vasalis-03.png'
>>>
```

However when I try to retrieve it using java with the following code

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFS;
import com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSDBFile;
import com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSInputFile;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import java.io.File;

public class RetrieveFileTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "playtest" );
    GridFS gfs = new GridFS(db, "attachments");

    System.out.println("getting file: " + args[0]);
    ObjectId fileId = new ObjectId(args[0]);
    GridFSDBFile gfsFile = gfs.findOne(fileId);
    File outFile = new File(gfsFile.getFilename());
    gfsFile.writeTo(outFile);
  }
}
```

I get this error message:

```
getting file: 5251ad0d56c02c34fbad2a3d
Oct 06, 2013 7:01:45 PM com.mongodb.DBPortPool gotError
WARNING: emptying DBPortPool to /127.0.0.1:27017 b/c of error
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.BasicDBList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSFile.put(GridFSFile.java:192)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONCallback.objectStart(BasicBSONCallback.java:69)
    at com.mongodb.DefaultDBCallback.objectStart(DefaultDBCallback.java:64)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONCallback.arrayStart(BasicBSONCallback.java:88)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decodeElement(BasicBSONDecoder.java:195)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder._decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:79)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.DefaultDBDecoder.decode(DefaultDBDecoder.java:61)
    at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:142)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:92)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:244)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:216)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:288)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:273)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:728)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:670)
    at com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFS.findOne(GridFS.java:191)
    at com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFS.findOne(GridFS.java:173)
    at nl.lntng.storm_project.RetrieveFileTest.main(RetrieveFileTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

And have no idea what to do with it.

Comment: what does the file metadata look like when you pull it out with python?

Comment: What's at at nl.lntng.storm_project.RetrieveFileTest.main(RetrieveFileTest.java:30)? I'm not sure from the example code which is line 30.

Comment: @Trisha I'm sorry. I cleaned the code up, but forgot to update the line in the error message. It corresponds to the line:

    GridFSDBFile gfsFile = gfs.findOne(fileId);

Comment: @tom with the python version, storing it results in an exact duplicate.